CSS Flex-Box: .map results exceed div container
I cannot "adjust" the results from an API query which are mapped with .map function to fit inside a div container. I am using react.
Here is my CSS:
.book-results-container {
    max-height: 250px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.book-results {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

And this is the code from the corresponding component:
<div className='book-results-container'>
  {books.map((book) => {
    const isbn13 = book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers?.find(identifier => identifier.type === 'ISBN_13')?.identifier || 'No ISBN_13 available';
    return (
      <div key={book.id} className='book-results'>
        <h3>{book.volumeInfo.title}</h3>
        <p>{book.volumeInfo.authors?.join(', ')}</p>
        <p>{book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}</p>
        <div className='book-isbn-container'>
                           
          <p>ISBN 13: {isbn13}</p>
          <button className="book-button-copy" onClick={() => copyToClipboard(isbn13)}>
            <box-icon color="white" name="copy"></box-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>    
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>

Here is a screenshot how it is rendered onto the viewport:


This looks like the problem will be in the style of the parent component, rather than the scrollable list. Could you include that in the question?

The overflow issue you're experiencing is not coming from the .book-results-container class. That class is working accordingly. The issue is from the the parent container with the gradient background. You should be setting the max-height of the book-results-container class to the height of the gradient container and setting the gradient container with an overflow: hidden property.

Thank you very much, Hamed. Your suggestion solves the problem.

Scrolling required the parent container to have a given height value, whether hard coded or something like height: 100%, which propagates up till it reaches a parent with a fixed value
For your case you should specify the height of the parent container
